# How to determine how much storage to store backups?

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, storage

I was thinking about this question ( Here where I work, we have a lot of space so backups are dayli ok ), and i'm thinking about if I was hired in another company, and see that they don't have backups, because there's no space.

How can I say " So, we need xTB of storage for the backups".?

There are some questions here and stackoverflow saying to use `sp_spaceused` to get an approach. But I think this is wrong because I made 3 tests, and all of them are wrongs. ( In one test, My database has 257MB of size, and `reserved space` on `sp_usedspace`is `109.064 KB`. When I create a backup, the backup has `24.729kb`).

Comment: Without doing a trend analysis in the Msdb backup history table, and adding some buffer to your calculation, its hard to predict. I have done this in past using backup history table in msdb and they give you a pretty good idea about when your X TB drive is going to get filled up. If no one posts an answer I will post an answer later - answering from a small screen is hard 

Comment: Is that backup compressed? SQL Server will only backup the 'used' pages, an easy way to see how much is used is `SELECT FILEPROPERTY(N'logcal_name',N'SpaceUsed')/128.0 [SpaceUsed_MB]`

Comment: Hey @kin,  I will follow your steps and see what I can get. Thank you very much. `dwjv`, no ,i'm thinking in this question with "normal" full backups in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in order to get the calculations correct to somewhat close to an appropriate figure would be collecting a data or a trend analysis as mentioned by Kin. There are various methods available to gather such data:

1. One approach would be analyzing a trend for the size of backup that has happened with its history being retained in msdb backup set from below query:

   ```
   SELECT
   [database_name] AS "Database",
   DATEPART(day,[backup_start_date]) AS "Day",
   AVG([backup_size]/1024/1024) AS "Backup Size MB",
   AVG([compressed_backup_size]/1024/1024) AS "Compressed Backup Size MB",
   AVG([backup_size]/[compressed_backup_size]) AS "Compression Ratio"
   FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
   WHERE [database_name] = N'Databasename'
   AND [type] = 'D'
   GROUP BY [database_name],DATEPART(dd,[backup_start_date]);
   ```

As you mentioned normal full backups, above should be OK, but it could be tedious if you have quite a large no of databases. But i believe you can come up with query on same with help of [sp_foreachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/). Also, make calculations based on the factor of retention period for the backups on that drive accordingly.

2. But the one which i have been using is this excellent article from Chad miller on [Database Space Capacity Planning](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/powershell/68011/) which with help of a Powershell and SQL script might do the trick by gathering the data say for next 15 days or a month to help you in deciding or predicting the Vol space for that particular drive ( in my case i have a dedicated backup drive, so this works good for me)

As said

> You can use the process described in the article to create a
>   consolidated space forecasting report, which focuses on a "days
>   remaining" metric. In addition, the use of PowerShell to collect data
>   and load into a SQL table as demonstrated in this article, provides a
>   solution you can easily adapt to many database administration problems

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was hired on a new job and I will test it as soon as possible.